# Why does changing ::content to ::slotted(..) not work?

Tags: css, polymer

**Enviroment:** Polymer 3

**Problem:**
I've changed the ::content to ::slotted, but then the style does not work:

*before change*

```
   .ContentWrapper,
      .ScrollAndHeaderContainer,
      :host ::content .my-data-grid--BaseHTMLWrapper {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        min-height: 0;
      }
```

*after change*

```
 .ContentWrapper,
      .ScrollAndHeaderContainer,
      :host ::slotted(.my-data-grid--BaseHTMLWrapper) {
        flex: 1 1 auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column nowrap;
        min-height: 0;
      }
```

This is how I use it:

```
<div class="my-data-grid--BaseHTMLWrapper">
```

The style does not work after this change.

Can someone give me an explanation why please? I've totally no clue.

Answer (score 0):

Here a working example which may help :

[DEMO](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/kjnmiRdyX3zbKDf8)

index.hml :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="custom-element.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>  

    <custom-element>
        <div slot = "test" class="my-data-grid--BaseHTMLWrapper" >SLOT TEST </div>
    </custom-element>

  </body>
</html>
```

custom-element.js:

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/polymer@3.0.0-pre.13/polymer-element.js';
class CustomElement extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
      <style>
        div ::slotted(.my-data-grid--BaseHTMLWrapper) {
          flex: 1 1 auto;
          display: flex;
          flex-flow: column nowrap;
          min-height: 0;

          font-family: sans-serif;
          color:red;

        }
      </style>
      <div><slot name='test'></slot></div>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('custom-element', CustomElement);
```